# How to capitalize Algorithm when referencing an algorithm using \autoref?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms, capitalization, autoref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   Then compute
   \begin{equation}
       a= b + c
   \end{equation} 
   }{ 

   Compute
      \begin{equation}  d = e + f \end{equation} 
  }
 }
 \caption{My Code}
 \label{lovely_algo}
\end{algorithm}

 \autoref{lovely_algo} is my algorithm. But this sentence is not grammatically correct. A in the algorithm should be capitalized. 

\end{document}
```

Here is a simple algorithm. I am referencing it using hyperref + autoref, which is my preferred reference method.

However, I wish that the A in the algorithm to be capitalized throughout. Otherwise some parts of the text will have grammatical mistake.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid `\autoref` doesn't do capitalisation. You can use the `cleveref` package instead. It has its own equivalent to `\autoref` in `\cref` and you can get a capitalised variant by using `\Cref` instead:

```latex
\Cref{lovely_algo} is my algorithm. But this sentence is not grammatically 
correct. A in the algorithm should be capitalized.
```

Load `cleveref` after `hyperref` to make sure they work together nicely.